# Read permissions in User Profile Service Application

Tags: 2013, user-profile

I am developing a webpart in SharePoint 2013 that must access the user profiles of users in the Active Directory. The problem is that when I try to access some user profile properties I get an "Unauthorized Exception" because my user is not the administrator.

My first guess is to add Everyone with read permissions in the User Profile Service Application in the CA but there is only Full Control Permissions option

[image]

Any other idea?

Comment: why don't use elevated privileges and give read permissions or whatever permissions you required to application pool account, not sure if that's the best practice though.

Comment: I had already tried runwith elevated privileges but didn't work.
Anything else I should try? Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried using the the CSOM or REST APIs instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a WebPart i conclude that you are using server side code. If thats right you can use elevated privileges to access the user profiles. BTW when you using elevated privileges your code runs under the user that is specified in your WebApplication's AppPool which is quite sure a System Account.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPSite site = new SPSite(http://server);
            SPWeb myweb = site.OpenWeb();
            SPUser found = myweb.AllUsers.GetByID(1);
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your amswer. I think I found the solution.
I gave Retrieve people data for search crawlers to Everyone account.
I will try this. Thank you again